# Why is glUniform1i() returning GL_INVALID_VALUE?

Tags: opengl, texture

I have a sampler variable in a shader:

```
 uniform sampler2DArray tiles;
```

Which I am trying to bind to a texture unit in GL:

```
    int tilesUniformIndex = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramId,"tiles");
    System.out.println("tiles: "+tilesUniformIndex);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgramId);
    glok();  // <- This calls glGetError() and throws exception if not-ok
    glUniform1i(tilesUniformIndex, GL_TEXTURE0 + TILE_TEXTURE_UNIT_INDEX);
    glok();
```

`TILE_TEXTURE_UNIT_INDEX` is a constant defined to be zero.

The location is being correctly introspected, output is:

```
 tiles: 7
```

which is the correct binding location I expect in context of the shader source.

The /second/ glok() is throwing an exception, with 0x501 GL_INVALID_VALUE.

According to [the documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml), this can only happen if the `count` parameter is less than zero.  But `glUniform1i` /doesn't have a count parameter/!

I've tried:

```
glUniform1iv(tilesUniformIndex, 1, new int[]{GL_TEXTURE0 + TILE_TEXTURE_UNIT_INDEX});
```

as well, and the implementation of that does what it looks like (passes a memory pointer to the array data as output `value`).

So, what gives?   Anyone know how this function can possibly behave like this?   This is a simple, correct use case, right?

Comment: `GL_TEXTURE0 + TILE_TEXTURE_UNIT_INDEX` You don't set sampler uniforms to OpenGL enumerators. You set them to the actual texture unit index. This isn't your actual problem, but it's non-functional never-the-less.

Comment: I take it the shader compiled successfully at both stages ? (compile & link)

Comment: Yup.  (the first glok() not throwing an exception indicates this, but I also checked GL_LINK_STATUS  with glProgram...)

Comment: I notice you're using a sampler2DArray, which isn't part of the GLSL spec (google tells me its an nvidia extension). But your glUniform1i example looks like it assuming the variable is a "sampler2D" - is this intentional ?  This is in addition to Nicol Bolas's point about the GL_TEXTURE0 issue.

Comment: sampler2Darray has been core GL since 3.0 / GLSL330.   It was an extension before that but it certainly, definitely, absolutely supported (wokring now, core profile, not nvidia hardware, no extensions, etc)